# ERROR: SQL Functions cannot return type trigger in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-triggers

I'm using PostgreSQL with pgAdmin and I can't get a trigger function to work. However, as far as I am aware, you can return type trigger in PostgreSQL?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate_Cat() 
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
  -- CODE here
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL;
    
CREATE TRIGGER validate_Cat
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON Category
FOR EACH ROW execute procedure validate_Cat();
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer.

Answer (score 24):

SOLVED, had to change language to `PLPGSQL`

Comment: i am getting this error: ERROR:  language "plpgsql" does not exist

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR:  SQL functions cannot return type trigger

When I tried to create the trigger function with `LANGUAGE SQL` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE SQL -- Here
AS $$
$$;
```

But, I could create the trigger function with `LANGUAGE plpgsql` without error as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql -- Here
AS $$
BEGIN
END;
$$;
```

In addition, I got the error below:

> ERROR:  SQL functions cannot return type event_trigger

When I tried to create the event trigger function with `LANGUAGE SQL` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func()
RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE SQL -- Here
AS $$
$$;
```

But, I could create the event trigger function with `LANGUAGE plpgsql` without error as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func()
RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql -- Here
AS $$
BEGIN
END;
$$;
```